Fit/stretch content/background to full page height when printing
I wanted to add some watermarks to my pages. Following this post, I'm able to add a background image to each of the pages. The code is as such.


$('.print').on('click', function () {
  setTimeout(function(){
    window.print();
  }, 1000);
})
.content {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
}
@media print {
  .content:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    inset: 0;
    background: 
      url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg style="transform:rotate(-90deg)" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  viewBox="0 0 50 60"><text x="0" y="25" fill="%23000">LORE</text></svg>') 
      0 0/100% 100vh;
    opacity: 25%;
    -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact !important;
  }
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1> Hello World!</h1>
<div class='content'>
  <a href="#" class="print">print</a>
  <div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere, deleniti obcaecati magnam optio enim, vitae nihil sed ad repellat modi necessitatibus sint. Repudiandae quaerat veritatis dolores consequatur blanditiis perferendis impedit?
  </div>
  <div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere, deleniti obcaecati magnam optio enim, vitae nihil sed ad repellat modi necessitatibus sint. Repudiandae quaerat veritatis dolores consequatur blanditiis perferendis impedit?
  </div>
  <div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere, deleniti obcaecati magnam optio enim, vitae nihil sed ad repellat modi necessitatibus sint. Repudiandae quaerat veritatis dolores consequatur blanditiis perferendis impedit?
  </div>
  <div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere, deleniti obcaecati magnam optio enim, vitae nihil sed ad repellat modi necessitatibus sint. Repudiandae quaerat veritatis dolores consequatur blanditiis perferendis impedit?
  </div>
  <div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere, deleniti obcaecati magnam optio enim, vitae nihil sed ad repellat modi necessitatibus sint. Repudiandae quaerat veritatis dolores consequatur blanditiis perferendis impedit?
  </div>
  <div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere, deleniti obcaecati magnam optio enim, vitae nihil sed ad repellat modi necessitatibus sint. Repudiandae quaerat veritatis dolores consequatur blanditiis perferendis impedit?
  </div>
  <div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere, deleniti obcaecati magnam optio enim, vitae nihil sed ad repellat modi necessitatibus sint. Repudiandae quaerat veritatis dolores consequatur blanditiis perferendis impedit?
  </div>
  <div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere, deleniti obcaecati magnam optio enim, vitae nihil sed ad repellat modi necessitatibus sint. Repudiandae quaerat veritatis dolores consequatur blanditiis perferendis impedit?
  </div>
  <div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere, deleniti obcaecati magnam optio enim, vitae nihil sed ad repellat modi necessitatibus sint. Repudiandae quaerat veritatis dolores consequatur blanditiis perferendis impedit?
  </div>
  <div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere, deleniti obcaecati magnam optio enim, vitae nihil sed ad repellat modi necessitatibus sint. Repudiandae quaerat veritatis dolores consequatur blanditiis perferendis impedit?
  </div>
  <div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere, deleniti obcaecati magnam optio enim, vitae nihil sed ad repellat modi necessitatibus sint. Repudiandae quaerat veritatis dolores consequatur blanditiis perferendis impedit?
  </div>
  <div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere, deleniti obcaecati magnam optio enim, vitae nihil sed ad repellat modi necessitatibus sint. Repudiandae quaerat veritatis dolores consequatur blanditiis perferendis impedit?
  </div>
  <div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere, deleniti obcaecati magnam optio enim, vitae nihil sed ad repellat modi necessitatibus sint. Repudiandae quaerat veritatis dolores consequatur blanditiis perferendis impedit?
  </div>
  <div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere, deleniti obcaecati magnam optio enim, vitae nihil sed ad repellat modi necessitatibus sint. Repudiandae quaerat veritatis dolores consequatur blanditiis perferendis impedit?
  </div>
  <div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere, deleniti obcaecati magnam optio enim, vitae nihil sed ad repellat modi necessitatibus sint. Repudiandae quaerat veritatis dolores consequatur blanditiis perferendis impedit?
  </div>
  <div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere, deleniti obcaecati magnam optio enim, vitae nihil sed ad repellat modi necessitatibus sint. Repudiandae quaerat veritatis dolores consequatur blanditiis perferendis impedit?
  </div>
  <div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere, deleniti obcaecati magnam optio enim, vitae nihil sed ad repellat modi necessitatibus sint. Repudiandae quaerat veritatis dolores consequatur blanditiis perferendis impedit?
  </div>
  <div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere, deleniti obcaecati magnam optio enim, vitae nihil sed ad repellat modi necessitatibus sint. Repudiandae quaerat veritatis dolores consequatur blanditiis perferendis impedit?
  </div>
  <div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere, deleniti obcaecati magnam optio enim, vitae nihil sed ad repellat modi necessitatibus sint. Repudiandae quaerat veritatis dolores consequatur blanditiis perferendis impedit?
  </div>
  <div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere, deleniti obcaecati magnam optio enim, vitae nihil sed ad repellat modi necessitatibus sint. Repudiandae quaerat veritatis dolores consequatur blanditiis perferendis impedit?
  </div>
  <div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere, deleniti obcaecati magnam optio enim, vitae nihil sed ad repellat modi necessitatibus sint. Repudiandae quaerat veritatis dolores consequatur blanditiis perferendis impedit?
  </div>
  <div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere, deleniti obcaecati magnam optio enim, vitae nihil sed ad repellat modi necessitatibus sint. Repudiandae quaerat veritatis dolores consequatur blanditiis perferendis impedit?
  </div>
  <div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere, deleniti obcaecati magnam optio enim, vitae nihil sed ad repellat modi necessitatibus sint. Repudiandae quaerat veritatis dolores consequatur blanditiis perferendis impedit?
  </div>
  <div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere, deleniti obcaecati magnam optio enim, vitae nihil sed ad repellat modi necessitatibus sint. Repudiandae quaerat veritatis dolores consequatur blanditiis perferendis impedit?
  </div>
</div>



Or codepen here.
However, if the content doesn't take the full height of a page, the background itself will also be cut off, with the word "LOR" being cropped in my given example.
So, the question is, is it possible to stretch the content/background to full height for each page? Or prevent the background from being cropped in the first place? Thanks~

why not use background-size within media print?

@tacoshy it's already included here
background:  url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg style="transform:rotate(-90deg)" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  viewBox="0 0 50 60"><text x="0" y="25" fill="%23000">LORE</text></svg>')        0 0/100% 100vh;
As it basically has 100% 100vh as its background-size

yeah but that will not work as you itnend. you properly need to use cover

@tacoshy cover? Just checked it cover for ALL pages, instead of each pages
